# Intercepting requests in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, netflix-ribbon

I have my service layer '`S`' calling data layer '`D_OLD`'. Now I am upgrading my `D_OLD` database version to `D_NEW`. But I want to test stability for a few days and if not stable, I want to rollback. But if I rollback, I must be able to replay all the transactions happened on new database to old database. 
What I am planning is to have two instances of `D`, one with new database and other running with old database.
I am planning to intercept all the `PUT/POST/DELETE` requests from `S` to `D_NEW` and put it in a `kafka` topic. I will have a job to replay that requests into `D_OLD`.

Now my S is a spring application using ribbon for making requests to D_NEW. I have tried `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor`, but seems it work only with `RestTemplate`.

Is there any way to intercept outgoing requests in ribbon/spring/tomcat?

Comment: In S, what HTTP client are you using?

Comment: Im using ribbon https://github.com/Netflix/ribbon/

Comment: If you are accessing the data layer with some kind of an interface why don't you make an implementation that after doing the changes in D_NEW does the same in D_OLD using the old data access services (in a separate thread or queue to avoid the extra delay) . You will register the new implementation (new beans registered to spring) then use both new and old and after time - remove the old ones. And just having one proxy implementation for the service class

Comment: @VeselinDavidov I dont want to overload my S with processing data for D_OLD as well. Some POST/PUT requests are very heavy.